# django htmx cannot get element name for the second time

Tags: python, django, htmx

In my views.py, I have 2 functions using "customer = request.GET.get('drf_customers')"
In list_drf_customer_branch() it works, but in list_customer_products() it returns null

Is there something wrong with my approach?

views.py:

```
def list_drf_customer_branch(request):
    template_name = "poc/partials/drf_customer_branch.html"

    customer = request.GET.get('drf_customers') # this works, returns id
    
    if customer == "":
        drf_customer_branch = None
    else:
        drf_customer_branch = models.CustomerBranch.objects.filter(
            customer=customer).order_by("description")

    context = {}
    context["drf_customer_branch"] = drf_customer_branch
    context["is_htmx_branch"] = True

    return render(request, template_name, context=context)


@login_required
def list_customer_products(request):
    template_name = "poc/partials/drf_customer_products.html"
    context = {}
    context["form"] = forms.DrfDetailForm

    customer = request.GET.get('drf_customers') # this doesnt work, returns None

    if customer == "":
        customer_products = None
    else:
        customer_products = models.CustomerProduct.objects.select_related("product__brand", "product__brand_category", "customer").filter(
            customer=customer).order_by("product__brand", "product__description")
    
    context["drf_customer_products"] = customer_products

    return render(request, template_name, context=context)
```

forms.html

```
            <div id="id_drf_customers" class="mb-3">
                {% include 'poc/partials/drf_customers.html' %}
            </div>

            <div id="id_drf_customers" class="mb-3">
                {% include 'poc/partials/drf_customer_branch.html' %}
            </div>

            <div id="id_drf_customer_products" class="mb-3">
                {% include "poc/partials/drf_customer_products.html" %}
            </div>
```

partials/drf_customers.html

```
<select 
    name="drf_customers" 
    class="select form-select" 
    id="id_drf_customers"
    hx-get="{% url 'poc:drf_customer_branch' %}" 
    hx-trigger="change" 
    hx-target="#id_drf_customer_branch"
    required >
    <option value="" selected disabled>Select Customer/Outlet</option>
    {% for i in drf_customers %}
    <option value="{{i.customer_id}}">{{i.customer_name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Can you include the other partials and the entire form.